# How to integrate a <script></script> into the content method of fancybox2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

I'm trying to load a javascript content inside the content method of fancybox.

```
<script>
$('#streaminput').on("click", function() {
  $('#streaminput').fancybox({ 
      width    : '95%', 
      height   : '95%', 
      autoSize    : false, 
      closeClick  : false, 
      fitToView   : false, 
      openEffect  : 'elastic', 
      closeEffect : 'none',
      content: '<script src="http://scriptfromanotherwebsite" idvideo="myid"></script>'

  });
});
</script>
```

I tried to send the `idvideo` in ajax and load the script in another page (with the iframe fancybox) without luck...

Thanks in advance

Comment: For one you MUST escape the end tag `<\/script>`

Comment: Thank the popup is displaying now but look like the script doesn't load inside the popup.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not used to **Fancybox** usage but hey you have **jQuery** to do the job for you.

So, How about using [jQuery.getScript()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) method.

> Description: Load a JavaScript file from the server using a GET HTTP
>   request, then execute it.

In your fancybox `beforeShow` or `beforeLoad` callbacks ,

```
beforeLoad: function(current, previous) {
          $.getScript("https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/blob/master/js/jquery.knob.js", function(){
               alert("Script Loaded");
           });
      }
```

I think this would do the trick for you.

After going through a few google search, i came up with a solution.
In your fancybox `beforeShow` or `beforeLoad` callbacks add this line to add a script  to the header section,

```
 var add_script = document.createElement('script');
 add_script.setAttribute('src','https://github.com/aterrien/jQuery-Knob/blob/master/js/jquery.knob.js');
 add_script.setAttribute('idvideo','mynameispawal');
 document.head.appendChild(add_script);
```

And i believe you can call AJAX inside `beforeshow` to access the value of `idvideo`.

And here is a [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PFVxK/1980/).

Comment: Yep that's was it ! Thank save my day.